# How is the segment size related to the number of bits in the buses?

Tags: memory, bus

If I have the width of each register as 32 bits, the width of the data bus is 16 bits and the width of the address bus is 24 bits, what is the segment size?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What research have you done?

Comment: it is not a homework question. i searched alot but in vain

Comment: Please see [ask] on how to improve your question. It is currently at risk for removal due to the low quality.

Answer (score 1):

it's not related.

The numbers given match the statistics of the `intel 80386-SX` which had a variable segment size. And also the `Motorola 68000` which did not use segments at all.